# What is the maximum sound output in dB provided by 3.5mm Audio port in Raspberry pi3?

Tags: pi-3

maximum sound output in dB provided by 3.5mm Audio port in Raspberry pi3?

Answer (score 1):

The 3.5 mm jack is supposed to be line output, not for driving speakers directly. So to produce any real dBs, you will need a separate amplifier. The dB's you get depend on your amplifier, not on the output of the Pi.

Also, the real dB you get depends also on the efficiency of the speakers.

Comment: How to set the dB level of .wav file using python? Also how to get the dB level of the wav file?

Comment: You can't. The Pi provides a line output. The amplifier behind it determines the dBs you get. If you turn the amplifier up to 10, it will produce more dBs than when it is on 5. The wav-file and your scripts stay the same when you turn up the volume.

Answer (score 1):

Get an amplifier with a dB meter. Then you will be able to measure the dB out put you get for a given volume you set in Python. Note that cheap dB meters are not accurate, but there are [expensive professional](https://tmi.yokogawa.com/solutions/products/power-analyzers/) meters if you need precision.